# How to find how many times nth day of the month has passed between two dates in Excel?

Tags: excel

Trying to come up with a formula that basically can tell me how many times the nth day of the month has passed between two dates in excel. Any ideas on where I can start? I can do it in VBA, but would prefer not to use VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(ROW(INDEX(ZZ:ZZ,A1):INDEX(ZZ:ZZ,B1)))=C1))
```

[image]

Comment: You realize, of course, that this will fail if any dates are later than `25-Nov-4770`   :-)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld if I and this site are around then, I will fix it so it works. :)

Comment: Wow Perfect! Can you explain your intuition for why this works? Would love to learn more.

Comment: `ROW(INDEX(ZZ:ZZ,A1):INDEX(ZZ:ZZ,B1))` creates an array of dates from the start to the finish.  Then we test that array if the day of the month equals the one desired.  If True then it counts as 1 if False then it counts as 0.  In the end it sums the results. @JohnnyJohn